# CDN yes or no in this case

Tags: cdn

Site that have nice but raising number of visits / hits, heavily operates on few database has 0.6 sec / req average serving time, most of that time is spend (about 30% / 0.2 sec/avg) on "first byte" so working on solving that problem.

Another way to improve speed that I considering is using CDN. I am not very sure can CDN in this case help:
-it all dynamic content
-have a lot of images
-already have internal caching (front end), (and caching on client side if that matters)

So, please tell me what you would suggest, should I try with CDN and how much improvement I can expect? (traffic is mostly US)

Comment: Well CDN will definitely help the load times because it will let you bypass the connection limit (per domain/subdomain) and will minimize the "real" distance to the end user (although if traffic is US only the different won't be much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @matthias says accept some of your other answers...

Whether a CDN will make much difference depends on how far they are from the server and what the latencies are like.

A CDN will give you more connections but you can do this by adding extra hostnames.

There are probably other ways of improving page load times, run a test on webpagetest.org and post the results.